# How to to add a menu separator for a menuitem in firefox's context menu

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to add a menu separator before and after my menuitem in firefox's contextmenu .
This is my expected output...

```
 |                     |
 |                     |
 |Select All           |
 |---------------------|
 |Show Meaning         |
 |---------------------|
 |                     |
```

My code...

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
        <menuseparator />
        <menuitem id="diction-show-meaning" label="Show meaning" oncommand="" insertafter="context-selectall"/>
        <menuseparator />
    </popup>
```

However the menu separators are appearing at the END of the context menu!

How does one enclose a menuitem for contentAreaContextMenu? 
I don't prefer to do it dynamically through java script. But let me know if that's the only way possible...

Comment: someone! please talk to me!

Comment: Check this:http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mozilla/thunderbird/suite/common/contentAreaContextOverlay.xul

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
    <menuitem id="diction-show-meaning" label="Show meaning" oncommand="" insertafter="context-sep-selectall"/>
    <menuseparator />
</popup>
```